# Python3 Flask app - how to prevent hardcoding IPv4 address in Python and/or HTML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am following [this Network Chuck YT video to learn basic Python Flask](https://youtu.be/5aYpkLfkgRE). I got the app working, but I am running it inside an Ubuntu "multipass" VM, so it cannot use the loopback address, `127.0.0.1`. When the app launches from the IPv4 address on port 8080 (currently `192.168.64.5`) and it works fine on initial launch, but the IP of the Ubuntu VM can (and will) change, **so I don't want to hardcode it**, if possible.

Here is my Python Flask code:

```
#!/bin/python

from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_meme():
    sr = "/wholesomememes"
    url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme" + sr
    url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
    response = json.loads(requests.request("GET", url).text)
    meme_large = response["preview"][-2]
    subreddit = response["subreddit"]
    return meme_large, subreddit

@app.route("/")
def index():
    meme_pic,subreddit = get_meme()
    return render_template("meme_index.html", meme_pic=meme_pic, subreddit=subreddit)

app.run(host="192.168.64.5", port=8080)
```

Here is my HTML for the webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Meme Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=http://192.168.64.5:8080/" />
<style>
body {background-color:#000000;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top-left}
h1 {text-align:center; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#000000}
p {text-align:center;font-family:Georgia, serif; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:48px;font-style:normal}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>A website to gather some memes!</h1>
<p>Here is your meme! This will refresh in 30 seconds!</p>
<p><img src="{{meme_pic}}"></p>
<p>Current subredddit: {{subreddit}} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to *not* hardcode the IPv4 address in either the Python Flask app *or* the HTML file?

**UPDATE** - final, fixed code here:

https://gitlab.com/kidacrimson/flask-memes

Comment: Maybe this? https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/flask+running+on+localhost+change+to+ip+address

Comment: shorter: `response = requests.get(url).json()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually servers can use `host="0.0.0.0"` to accept clients from all Network Cards installed in computer - `lan`, `wifi` and `loopback` (`127.0.0.1`).

And pages can use urls like `url=/` without `http://192.168.64.5:8080`

Comment: Thanks, @furas. The initial page works, but the reload fails. What should I use in the HTML file instead of 0.0.0.0 ? `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=http://0.0.0.0:8080/" />`

Comment: NM, I fixed it by simply removing the `url=` section from the HTML:  
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;"/>`

Comment: in answer I suggested `url=/` for refreshing